# Timeout while waiting for a reply from the bitbake server (60s)

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

Okay, So this error

```
Timeout while waiting for a reply from the bitbake server (60s)
```

will be occur if we installing a toolchain

```
nadim@nadim:~/var-fslc-yocto/build_xwayland$ bitbake meta-toolchain
Timeout while waiting for a reply from the bitbake server (60s)
```

```
Board: Variscite imx8mm  dart mini
Common targets: core-image-minimal
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGGgW.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we discourage **images** which just contain a **text**. Instead, paste the text directly into the question post. You could format the pasted text as a code. See also [ask].

Comment: What are the last lines in bitbake-cookerdaemon.log ?

Comment: I encountered this when bitbake didn't exit cleanly. Ususally I find bitbake processes still running in the background using `ps`, which I then kill.

Answer (score 2):

Remove bitbacke.lock file

`rm -rf bitbake.lock`

Then bitbake your image

`bitbake core-image-minimal`